# How do I display full string in a CodeQL exported result?

Tags: codeql

Converting `a.getChild(1)` to a string using `toString()`

*test.ql*

```
/**
 * @id custom
 * @kind problem
 * @problem.severity warning
 *
 */
import javascript

from ObjectExpr oe, Property p1, int i, AstNode a
where p1 = oe.getProperty(i) and
    p1.getName() = "fragment" and
    a = p1.getAChild().getAChild() and
    a.toString().indexOf("name") > -1
select a, a.getChild(1).toString()
```

Here is the codeql command used for generating a csv result file:

```
codeql database analyze ~/test.com ./test.ql --format=csv --output=results.csv
```

For example:
`a.getChild(1).toString() = PageLoadablePageWrapperQuery`
will be saved in the csv file like
`PageLo ... rQuery` instead of the full string.

How do I have the full string in the exported csv result?

Comment: Could you add a fragment of the JavaScript code that contains such an object expression with the correct properties and child structure? That would make it easier to reproduce and try out some approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the JavaScript library in CodeQL the shortening of long names in `.toString()` is hardcoded*. See https://github.com/github/codeql/blob/7361ad977a5dd5252d21f5fd23de47d75b763651/javascript/extractor/src/com/semmle/js/extractor/TextualExtractor.java#L121:

```java
public static String sanitiseToString(String str) {
    if (str.length() > 20) str = str.substring(0, 7) + " ... " + str.substring(str.length() - 7);
```

However, it is not very difficult to modify the source code such that `codeql database analyze` skips this part of the string sanitation. This can be done using the following steps:

1. download `TextualExtractor.java` from the url above and comment or remove the mentioned if-statement
2. find the location of `extractor-javascript.jar` in the installation of CodeQL, which is something like `codeql/javascript/tools/`
3. compile the modified file using the following line:

```
javac -cp ".:/path/to/codeql/javascript/tools/extractor-javascript.jar" TextualExtractor.java`
```

4. extract the jar file, replace `TextualExtractor.class` in the directory `com/semmle/js/extractor/`, and re-compress the jar file
5. re-install the javascript pack with `codeql pack install --force` from the directory that contains `qlpack.yml`, i.e., the project root
6. regenerate your CodeQL project database with

```
codeql database create dbname --overwrite --language=javascript --source-root=/path/to/project
```

7. run the query again.

Tested with the following JavaScript file:

```js
var PageLoadablePageWrapperQuery = "some query";

var p = {  // object literal containing five property definitions
  longtobetruncatedfragment: PageLoadablePageWrapperQuery,
  y: 1,
  diag: function() { return this.x - this.y; },
  get area() { return this.x * this.y; },
  set area(a) { this.x = Math.sqrt(a); this.y = Math.sqrt(a); }
};
```

and the following query:

```
/**
 * @id custom
 * @kind problem
 * @problem.severity warning
 *
 */
import javascript

from ObjectExpr oe, Property p1, int i, AstNode a
where p1 = oe.getProperty(i) and
    p1.getName() = "longtobetruncatedfragment" and
    a = p1.getAChild()
select a, a.toString()
```

Resulting csv:

```
,,"warning","longtobetruncatedfragment","/testfile.js","4","3","4","27"
,,"warning","PageLoadablePageWrapperQuery","/testfile.js","4","30","4","57"
```

*Interestingly for other languages, for example the Python library, the sanitation step is not implemented.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. But may I ask in which path do we execute `codeql pack install --force`?

Comment: It worked! By the way, do you have any idea why there is a sanitation step in the javascript library?

Comment: @Benassin you probably figured it out but `pack install` should be run to install `qlpack.yml`, from the directory that contains that file, which is the project root. About the reason for sanitation: I don't know, it might be that the messages are primarily intended to be displayed in an IDE like Visual Studio Code, and there the space in the window is limited, so in order to get a good overview long names are truncated. Also in the IDE you can click through to the source so you can find out easily what the full string is.